# C++ Unit Test Native C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tdd

First, a little background:

At work, I've inherited a large C++ program (a language I haven't used extensively in 12 years). To help myself better understand the application and how it fits together, I thought, "I love TDD, why not write some unit tests!". I've since spent two days getting a simple unit test to compile. I'm at the point where it gets to the linker, but I get the following error:

```
CIniReader* reader = new CIniReader("");


Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CIniReader::CIniReader(char *)" (??0CIniReader@@$$FQAE@PAD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall ApogeeTests::UnitTest1::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@UnitTest1@ApogeeTests@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ) C:\Users\champad\Documents\Applications\Leading Hedge\src\Apogee.Tests\UnitTest1.obj    Apogee.Tests
```

Now, I can resolve this buy setting the project that this lives in to a static library, rather than a DLL project (Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type).

My question is this:  MUST I do this? It seems there has to be a way for the linker to identify the functions it needs at compile time without having to constantly switch all 24 projects to lib when I want to unit test, and back when I need to deploy it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is probably due to how Your unit test app links to runtime libraries see Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library. Both (your unit test app and libraries it uses) should have the same type of runtime library.

Comment: The project was set to multithread DLL, so I changed the test project to the same, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Have You specified the library in linker input of Your unit test app?

Comment: I added a reference to it under common properties, and set it to link library dependencies and use library dependency inputs. Didn't resolve the linker error.

Comment: You mentioned You have a lot of projects in Your solution have You referenced all needed to compile? Sometimes libraries have dependencies on other libraries which need to be linked to Your app explicitly.

Comment: I'm only using the one library that has the code I"m looking to test. That library has the header and source files needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not exactly what I was looking for, this is what I'm doing unless anyone has a better suggestion!

I added a new project configuration and called it UnitTesting. Under that configuration, all the C++ projects are static libraries that the unit test project can reference. I figure I change the configuration before deploying, so this would be easy for me to remember.

While not ideal, this is working. But if there is a better way, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio creates a static library for each DLL you create, specifically for linking with client code.

If your project has the following modules:

```
core-functionality.dll
unit-tests.exe
```

Then your unit-tests.exe will either load APIs from core-functionality.dll using LoadLibrary and family and casting the resulting function pointers to the correct types (this is ugly, error prone and difficult to maintain), or it can link statically, against core-functionality.**lib** (this should be generated during the build of core-functionality.dll).

I think you are looking for the second option.